# Java generate setter query names

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql

I am building an entity and i need to populate all the fields from a result set from a jpql resultset like like so:

```
    summary.setPeriod_1((BigDecimal)object[4]);
    summary.setPeriod_2((BigDecimal)object[5]);
    summary.setPeriod_3((BigDecimal)object[6]);
    summary.setPeriod_4((BigDecimal)object[7]);
```

The problem is that there are 50x periods and it looks ugly and takes up lots of space.

is it possible to do it as a for loop something like this:

```
for(int i=1; i<54; i++){
summary.setPeriod_[i]((BigDecimal)object[i+4]);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you be better with an `addPeriod(int position, BigDecimal period)` method?

Comment: You have to loop using the reflexion and call the method by his name as a string https://stackoverflow.com/a/161005/4479402

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try something a bit like this.

```
java.lang.reflect.Method method;
try {
  for(int i=1; i<54; i++){
       method = summary.getClass().getMethod("setPeriod_"+i, BigDecimal.class);
       method.invoke(summary, object[i]);
  }
} catch (SecurityException e) { ... }
  catch (NoSuchMethodException e) { ... }
  catch (IllegalArgumentException e) { ... }
  catch (IllegalAccessException e) { ... }
  catch (InvocationTargetException e) { ... }
```

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: @Djory I keep getting an illegal argument error.  What is "obj" supposed to be in your example?

Comment: My bad, this is the instance of class that you need. in this case it was summary.